# Solspace's Date Field Filter - can it do date headings?

Tags: solspace, date, filter

I've started using Solspace's *Date Field Filter* plugin. Is there any way to make the plugin show yearly headings? Something equivalent to EE's {date_heading display="yearly"}, which doesn't work with the plugin.

I've got a list of awards that I want to break up by date on a single page, e.g. 2013 winners, 2012 winners, etc.

The current work-around is to set the entry date as the award date, but I'd rather not do it that way (for a variety of reasons).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Date Field Filter* works with the `{exp:channel:entries}` tag, so the native use of {date_heading} in {exp:channel:entries} should apply here. See the [EE documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#date-heading). However, {date_heading} is for **entry_date**, not a custom Date field.

How about PHP for this then? Basically, display a heading when the first occurrence of a year is encountered, and store it in a PHP array to avoid displaying the same year again.

```
<?php $heading = array(); ?>
{exp:channel:entries /* your other parameters here, including Date Field Filter parameters */}

    <?php if( ! isset($heading['{my_date_field format="%Y"}']) ) :?>
        <h2>{my_date_field format="%Y"} winners</h2>
        <?php $heading['{my_date_field format="%Y"}'] = '{my_date_field format="%Y"}'; ?>
    <?php endif ?>

    // Your other code

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Excellent. Tested it out and it works. Thanks.

Edit: For anyone else trying this - note that you do have to turn on the "allow php" in EE's template manager.