# Solspace Calendar: Year Header

Tags: solspace-calendar, calendar-events

I'm using the `exp:calendar:events` tag with Solspace Calendar. Is there a convenient way to output a year header, similar to `exp:channel:entries` in my events output?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

How about something similar to the method using PHP described here?:
[Solspace's Date Field Filter - can it do date headings?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/17162/solspaces-date-field-filter-can-it-do-date-headings/17189)

I'll rehash the answer here with modifications:

Basically, display a heading when the first occurrence of a year is encountered, and store it in a PHP array to avoid displaying the same year again.

```
<?php $heading = array(); ?>
{exp:calendar:events /* your other parameters here */}

    <?php if( ! isset($heading['{event_start_date format="%Y"}']) ) :?>
        <h2>{event_start_date format="%Y"}</h2>
        <?php $heading['{event_start_date format="%Y"}'] = '{event_start_date format="%Y"}'; ?>
    <?php endif ?>

    // Your other code

{/exp:calendar:events}
```

Don't forget to enable PHP for your template.

By the way, if you're looking for a chronological list of events, you should use `{exp:calendar:cal}` instead of `{exp:calendar:events}`. {exp:calendar:cal} will order occurrences stemming from different event entries in the correct timeline order. In other words, occurrences that overlap on a timeline will be ordered correctly and chronologically (e.g. *AABABABBB* instead of *AAAABBBBB*). See this more detailed explanation page for more details: http://www.solspace.com/docs/calendar/getting_started/